# Accessibility: wrapping list items in buttons for better keyboard navigation/accessibility

Tags: html, accessibility

I frequently have use cases in my application where i need a list of items which need to be interactive, like clicking on an item should perform some action.

I usually wrap up the list item (`li`) content in a `button`, which kinda makes sense as the list item is interactive. This also helps with making the list items keyboard accessible with <kbd>TAB</kbd>. But, as much as i understand, this also poses a problem that a keyboard user would have to <kbd>TAB</kbd> through the whole list to get out off it. Would it be better instead to manage focus in the list using something like [roving tabindex](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/radio/radio-1/radio-1.html) and allow ARROW keys for navigation within the list and <kbd>TAB</kbd> to focus in and out of the list ?

I am seeking validation for whether or not this is a good way to implement this kind of functionality, and pointers to any real world implementations

Answer (score 3):

My real world experience is that you shouldn't put anything inside a button which is not related to a button semantic role. And strictly speaking, you shouldn't put list items inside anything that isn't a list.

Putting the buttons inside the list items would be better, but read on.

A list of items that 'perform some action' is (semantically) a menu, (or perhaps a toolbar which is much like a menu, but doesn't have the open/close feature expected of menus).

So you should get good results if you put `role="menu"` on the element containing the buttons, and `role="menuitem"` on the buttons.

Don't put the button that opens the menu (the "menu button") inside the menu. (I've wasted a lot of time on this).

There is no "menubutton" role. Just use an html `<button>` or something else with `role="button"`. Then associate the menu button with the menu using `aria-controls="yourMenuID"`. There are some other aria attributes you should use too, such as `aria-expanded="true"/"false"` (on both menu and menu button - and kept in sync with javaScript) and `aria-haspopup="true"` on the menu button.

If you take a little care, you can use CSS attribute selectors to style the menu according to the aria attributes. For example:

```
*[role='menu'][aria-expanded='false'] {
  display:none;
}
*[role='menu'][aria-expanded='true'] {
  display:block;
}
```

**And yes, you should manage focus**. Either with the roving tabindex technique or `aria-activedescendant`. I prefer the latter because it makes things more explicit but roving tabindex seems slightly more common. Both techniques are well-supported across a range of browser/AT combinations.

There are clear recommendations for how accessible menus should behave (with links to example code) [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#menu). Menu button and toolbar behavior is described further down in the same document. It's an excellent resource.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for this great info. some clarification: I wasn't suggesting to put buttons inside list directly but more like <ul><li><button> content </button></li></ul>. I understand your point about the functionality being semantically like a menu, butdo not agree to it completely. in my case, there is no menu button to open the menu, this is always visible but it is not like a menubar, and clicking on an item changes content in another panel.

Comment: Semantically it is a list of similar items with similar attributes, like a list of fruit objects with name and type property, on clicking of any of these items, we change the image displayed in a nearby DOM element

Comment: Ok, if it doesn't open and close then I guess 'toolbar' is the best fit. But Your suggestion of `<ul><li><button> content </button></li></ul>` is ok too. Consider using `aria-controls` to associate each control with the corresponding content that changes in the other panel. Good luck!